# Stopping infinit loop from php script run in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, php, exit, start-stop-daemon

I am currently following a tutorial that teaches how to create a queue in php. An infinite loop was created in a php script. I simplified the code in order to focus on the question at hand:

```
while(1) {
        echo 'no jobs to do - waiting...', PHP_EOL;
        sleep(10);  
}
```

I use PuTTy (with an SSH connection) to connect to the linux terminal in my shared hosting account (godaddy). If I run `php queuefile.php` in the terminal, I know it will run with no problems (already tested the code with a finite **for loop** instead of the infinite **while loop**).

**QUESTION:** How could I exit out of the infinite loop once it has started? I have already read online the option of creating code that **"checks"** if it should continue looping with something like the following code:

```
$bool = TRUE; 
while ($bool)
{
  if(!file_exists(allow.txt)){$bool = FALSE}
  //... the rest of the code
```

though I am curious if there might be a command I can type in the terminal, or a set of keys I can push that will cause the script to terminate. If there is any way of terminating the script, or if there is a better way to make the previous **"check"**, I would love your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you didn't install any signal handlers, you can send SIGINT to the process by pressing Ctrl-C if it in the foreground. If it is not in the foreground, you can use `pkill -INT -f '^php queuefile.php$'`.

By default, `php` will quit on receiving SIGINT.

If, for some reason, there is a signal handler installed, you can also try the `TERM` signal (the default with `pkill`), and ultimately if you can find no reasonable signal to kill the process with, you can use the (violent and forceful) `SIGKILL`, by passing `-TERM` to `pkill` in place of `-INT`.

Comment: OH I see, and If for instance I had something running in the background before having entered the terminal, then performing `pkill -INT -f '^php queuefile.php$'` would terminate it, even though I had not called the php script to run from the terminal just before atempting to terminate the script?

Comment: @Webeng It would send SIGINT, which may or may not terminate it, but generally the answer is yes.